# How to design IBAction buttons

Tags: swift3

I want to design a button. Its even working on IBOutlets buttons just like that

```
@IBOutlet var myButton:UIButton!
```

but if someone wants that button to do an action what can he/she do

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject){}
```

Comment: Connect this action with your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control drag from the button to your function. If you look to the left of your `@IBAction` you will see a little empty circle. You can control drag from that to your button on the storyboard.